# html2fpdf problem

Tags: php, html, pdf, html2pdf

When submitting the following html to my html2pdfconverter.php file, the *biological info* and *illness and injury* heading gets omitted from the export:

```
<div id = "container" style="width: 625px;">
    <div id = "leftcontainer">
        <h4>Biological Information</h4>
        <div id = "bioinfo">
            <ul>
                <li><span>Morning Bodyweight (kg): </span></li>
                <li><span>Evening Bodyweight (kg): </span></li>
                <li><span>Morning Heart Rate (bpm): </span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <h4>Fatigue & Recovery</h4>
        <div id = "fatigue">
            <ul>
                <li><span>Estimated Fluid Consumption (Litres):</span></li>
                <li><span>Sleep Quality:</span></li>
                <li><span>Sleep Quantity (Hours): </span></li>
                <li><span>Mental Recovery:</span></li>
                <li><span>Physical Recovery:</span></li>
                <li><span>Pre-Training Energy:</span></li>
                <li><span>Muscle Soreness:</span></li>
                <li><span>General Fatigue:</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>                                                
    </div>
    <div id = "rightcontainer">                                                                                   
        <h4>Illness & Injury</h4>
        <div id = "illness">
            <ul>
                <li><span>Are You Ill:</span></li>
                <li><span>Are You Injured:</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <h4>Training</h4>
        <div id = "training">
            <ul>
                <li><span>Morning Session Duration (minutes):</span></li>
                <li><span>Morning Session Intensity:</span></li>
                <li><span>Evening Session Duration (minutes):</span></li>
                <li><span>Evening Session Intensity:</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <h4>General Comments</h4>
        <div id = "comments">
            <ul>
                <li><span>General Feedback (10 - 100 characters):</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get the following:

```
<div id = "container" style="width: 625px;">
    <div id = "leftcontainer">
        <div id = "bioinfo">
            <ul>
                <li><span>Morning Bodyweight (kg): </span></li>
                <li><span>Evening Bodyweight (kg): </span></li>
                <li><span>Morning Heart Rate (bpm): </span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <h4>Fatigue & Recovery</h4>
        <div id = "fatigue">
            <ul>
            <li><span>Estimated Fluid Consumption (Litres):</span></li>
                <li><span>Sleep Quality:</span></li>
                <li><span>Sleep Quantity (Hours): </span></li>
                <li><span>Mental Recovery:</span></li>
                <li><span>Physical Recovery:</span></li>
                <li><span>Pre-Training Energy:</span></li>
                <li><span>Muscle Soreness:</span></li>
                <li><span>General Fatigue:</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id = "rightcontainer">                                                                                        
        <div id = "illness">
            <ul>
                <li><span>Are You Ill:</span></li>
                <li><span>Are You Injured:</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <h4>Training</h4>
        <div id = "training">
            <ul>
                <li><span>Morning Session Duration (minutes):</span></li>
                <li><span>Morning Session Intensity:</span></li>
                <li><span>Evening Session Duration (minutes):</span></li>
                <li><span>Evening Session Intensity:</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <h4>General Comments</h4>
        <div id = "comments">
            <ul>
                <li><span>General Feedback (10 - 100 characters):</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This must have something to do with the fact that they both are the first heading underneath a div section...I'm just not sure why they are not being exported.

The correct HTML is being sent to the html2pdf generator file.

If I change the h4 tag to a p tag it works...but it doesn't work on any other header tags...Has anyone else come across this problem?

Comment: Weird. Does it work if you remove the ampersand? Is the HTML valid?

Comment: I know it is weird. The HTML is exactly as above. I think this is valid. It is not the ampersand as 'Fatigue & Recovery' are printed...It's something to do with the very first heading after a child div of container...

Answer (score 0):

I have a rather clunky solution, but hey it works....

What I did was add an empty div above the first heading underneath each new div.

e.g.

```
<div id = "leftcontainer">
<div></div>
<h4>Biological Information</h4>
.
.
.
</div>
```